# Keras error when applying multiple categorys for prediction

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, classification

I have some text data and I have followed all the steps here: https://jjallaire.github.io/deep-learning-with-r-notebooks/notebooks/6.1-using-word-embeddings.nb.html

However I have adapted it for my own problema. In the above example the authors use a classification of 0 or 1. However in my model I want to classify 1,2,3,4,5. However I get the following error:

````
 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: You are passing a target array of shape (15433, 1) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. `categorical_crossentropy` expects targets to be binary matrices (1s and 0s) of shape (samples, classes). If your targets are integer classes, you can convert them to the expected format via:
```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_binary = to_categorical(y_int)
```

Alternatively, you can use the loss function `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead, which does expect integer targets.
````

The code I am using is the following:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_embedding(input_dim = max_words, output_dim = embedding_dim, 
                  input_length = maxlen) %>% 
  layer_flatten() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 32, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 5, activation = "softmax")


model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "rmsprop",
  loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train,
  epochs = 20,
  batch_size = 32,
  validation_data = list(x_test, y_test)
)
```

With x_train and x_test being text data and y_train  and y_test being the 1,2,3,4,5 classifications.

```
> unique(y_test)
[1] 5 3 4 2 1
> unique(y_train)
[1] 2 3 1 5 4
```

Any help in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. One hot encode your data:

```
history <- model %>% fit(
  x_train, to_categorical(y_train -1),
  epochs = 20,
  batch_size = 32,
  validation_data = list(x_test, to_categorical(y_test-1))
)
```

2. Use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss:

```
model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "rmsprop",
  loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train -1,
  epochs = 20,
  batch_size = 32,
  validation_data = list(x_test, y_test-1)
)
```

Note that you need to `-1` in your `y` because Keras will take integers starting at zero.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that and it seems to fix my problem! I will be more careful in the preprocessing. I was obtaining massive negative numbers as my loss and now the loss is positive and looks  much better!

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are passing integer labels (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.) instead of one-hot encoded labels (e.g. `[1,0,0]`, `[0,1,0]`, `[0,0,1]`) to your model. However, since you are using `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function you must pass one-hot encoded labels. But, you can use the equivalent sparse version of that loss function, i.e. `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, without any need for modifying your labels:

```
model %>% compile(
  loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", ...
)
```

Further, make sure the labels start from 0 and not 1 (i.e. the integer labels must be in the set {0, 1, 2, ..., NUM_CLASSES-1}).

Comment: Thanks! this seems to have fixed the issue!